# How to test function use switch case by mockery Laravel

Tags: laravel, mockery

***function use switch-case***

```
switch ($mCorp->item_category) {
            case __('common.holiday'):
                $holiday[] = $mCorp->item_id;
                break;
            case __('common.development_reaction'):
                $developmentResponse[] = $mCorp->item_id;
                break;
        };
```

***I have not found a solution to this problem. Please help me a few ideas***

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to test... are you trying to test the above code block? Is this located inside a Laravel model? What are you trying to use Mockery for? Add more details in your question.

Comment: I want to test the return value when simulating the choices